# How to set multiple views of one model in odoo 10?

Tags: python, odoo

I'm setting up multiple views (tree, form) of a model.

I have two tree views and form views where I need to open Tree 2 view as record.

When clicking tree 2 record then open Form 2 as detail page.
Currently I have set Tree view sequence 1 working but still opening Form 1 instead of Form2.

How I can do this?

Comment: Could you add more details? Adding the code of the views for example

Answer (score 2):

If you want to specify the views to use, you can add a `context` attribute, and specify a view id for each type of view supported, exactly like the action's `view_id` attribute:

```
<field name="order_line" colspan="4" nolabel="1" context="{'form_view_ref' : 'module.view_id', 'tree_view_ref' : 'model.view_id'}"/>
```

If you don't specify the views, OpenERP will choose one in this order :

- It will use the <form> or <tree> view defined inside the field (see below)
- Else, it will use the views with the highest priority for this object.
- Finally, it will generate default empty views, with all fields.

> Note
> The context keys are named `<view_type>_view_ref`.
>
> By default, OpenERP will never use a view that is not defined for your object. If you have two models, with the same fields, but a different model name, OpenERP will never use the view of one for the other, even if one model inherit another.
> You can force this by manually specifying the view, either in the action or in the context.

Answer (score 0):

From https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/business_and_other/9781789618921/10/ch10lvl1sec104/adding-a-menu-item-and-window-action

Your can use the following code:

```
<act_window id="action_books2"
      name="All books"
      res_model="library.books"
      view_mode="tree,form"
      domain="[--any domain--]"
      context="{'--any context--'}" />
```

And then you define the action for the tree view and another one for form,view:

```
<record id="action_books2_tree" model="ir.actions.act_window.view">
    <field name="act_window_id" ref="action_books2" />
    <field name="view_id" ref="view_all_books2_tree" />
    <field name="view_mode">tree</field>
    <field name="sequence" eval="2"/>
</record>

<record id="action_all_books2_form" model="ir.actions.act_window.view">
    <field name="act_window_id" ref="action_all_books2" />
    <field name="view_id" ref="view_books2_form" />
    <field name="view_mode">form</field>
    <field name="sequence" eval="2"/>
</record>
```